# rendering updating only nessary movment

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Is there away to render update the objects that move while the back drop will be in scene? I have a huge scene setup it takes 3 to 4 mins per frame to render on the 1920 x 1080, I have learned many things to reduce render time while keeping good quality but in scene where camera doesn't move, only the character or car etc. I would like to render only updating the movement rather than doing whole picture but keeping the background in the render. When I have a good video editing software I know I can croma key characters etc. But would be nice to able to skip that process if possible.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48902/how-to-stop-blender-from-rendering-world/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't see it until now, didn't know that there is a inbox messages on this site. Your answer makes good sense basically kind a what I was thinking, but you but I didn't know I can render images with transiency's, which is awesome! I am likely to use Blenders Render farm for my big work. I am exited that their rates are cheap enough so I can get this animation on the road. Thank you for your answer. Sorry for the delay.