# Render time being wasted on empty frames

Tags: modeling, rendering, animation, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

Can someone please explain to me why blender is spending time on empty frames? I literally spent ages reducing the number of frames to less than a half so I can speed up my rendering time. But all that work is just useless because it is just spending time rendering the empty frames anyway? Any suggestion please?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15649/can-frames-with-no-animation-be-automatically-skipped https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32127/is-there-a-way-to-have-cycles-skip-rendering-alpha/  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48902/how-to-stop-blender-from-rendering-world/

Comment: Are the empty frames scattered through the animation, or are they all after the last frame that you actually want to render?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the question. The empty frames are just parts of the animation which are not keyframed. When I am watching the live render, they seem to be rendering along with th keyframes. I can see the frame count and each frame being rendered. I don't expect empty frames to render so I am just confused why as it is eating into render time.